# Cannot find the .apk file in my android project

Tags: android, eclipse, eclipse-adt

I have developed an android project using eclipse for android. I was developed it through importing a sample project. But there was only .project file after I am opening the project folder. I searched the .apk file everywhere in my drive. But I could not find it. How do I find my APK file?

Comment: in your project in eclipse there is bin folder see bin folder there is your apk file but after run your project

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have already compiled this project, you can find .apk file inside bin folder in project folder. Otherwise compiled and run the project as an android application, when the project is automatically generate the .apk file inside the bin folder.

Answer (score 2):

To get the .apk file first you need to run the application and and after successful running you can find the .apk file in bin folder of your application.

Answer (score 0):

There are two type of APK one Singed APK and Unsigned APK while you are comple and run your app in emulator at that time unsinged APK generated that you can find

```
 yourProjectFolder --> Bin --> yourproject.APK
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

**Make a Signed and Unsigned apk from eclipse :**

How to get Unsigned apk :

```
 -> Run project 
 -> Open bin directory and get youappname.apk
```

**OR**

```
-> Right click on project
-> Android Tools -> Export Unsigned Application Package
-> Then specify the file location for the signed .apk.
```

How to get Signed apk :

```
-> Right click on project.
-> Android Tools -> Export Signed Application Package
-> Then specify the file location for the signed .apk.
```

Answer (score -1):

Your Project `Loation\Application Name\app\build\outputs\apk`
`(C:\Users\samsung\Desktop\Name of your APp\app\build\outputs\apk)`